# MultipleValidationErrors with batchGetItem in DynamoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to make a filter to obtain more than one record in a DynamoDB table. I'm using the function batchGetItem with NodeJS inside an AWS Lambda as the API. Below is what my params look like.

Note: I tried multiple ways to create those params. I used single/double quotes/no quotes; I also passed each item with its type ( {PK: {S: 'Request#10001'}} ), and none of those worked.

Context: my table name is RequestTable, and it has a column named "PK" (defined as String) and "SK" (defined as String). If I apply the exact same filter in the DynamoDB UI (ex: PK == "Request#10001" AND SK == "Client"), it works.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const params = {
    RequestItems: {
        "RequestTable": {
            Keys: [
                {PK: 'Request#10001', 'SK': 'Client'},
                {PK: 'Request#10002', 'SK': 'Client'}
            ]
        }
      }
    }

client.batchGetItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      data.Responses.RequestTable.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        console.log(element);
      });
    }
  });
```

However, I'm not able to make this work, because I keep having errors that look like this:

```
Error MultipleValidationErrors: There were 6 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'RequestItems' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'TableName' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'IndexName' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ExpressionAttributeNames' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ExpressionAttributeValues' found in params
```

Any ideas on how could I solve that?

I tried playing around with the options available and trying to make it look like the following AWS resources: [Read in Batch AWS DynamoDB Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write-batch.html), but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of issues with your code:

1. You use high level syntax with the low-level client. Take some time to familiarise yourself with the [different available clients](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/exploring-amazon-dynamodb-sdk-clients/)
2. You use SDK V2, while SDK V3 is the current default and allows your application to be much leaner, as its modular:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, BatchWriteCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const ddbDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

async function batchGetItems() {
 
  try {
    return await ddbDocClient.send(
        new BatchGetCommand({
          RequestItems: {
            RequestTable: {
              Keys: [
                {PK: 'Request#10001', 'SK': 'Client'},
                {PK: 'Request#10002', 'SK': 'Client'}
              ],
            },
          },
        })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

batchGetItems()
    .then((data) =>
        console.log("BatchGetCommand succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)))
    .catch((error) => console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)));
```

3. Regardless if you use SDK V2/V3 the parameter syntax will be the same, so you can utilize the same syntax as I provided for params for the V2 DocumentClient.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Leeroy! I'll check it. However, I have a question... I'm trying to GET items, not PUT items. That's why I use the batchGetItems, not batWriteItems function

Comment: Oh, apologies, same rules apply. Let me update the code for BatchGetItems.